# Spring REST API design of search/filter

Tags: java, spring, rest, api-design, spring-rest

I've a URL something like this

```
GET  /users?filters[status]=active&filters[org][country]=IND&page[offset]=10&page[limit]=10&include[]=resource1&include[]=resource2
```

What is the best way to bind the request parameters in spring get method

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to append queries in your URL while using the HTTP GET method,
 `@RequestParam & @PathVariable` but both have completely different approaches.
One can easily differentiate between the approached used by looking at the URL itself.
In your case, @RequestParam must be used:

`GET  /users?filters[status]=active&filters[org][country]=IND&page[offset]=10&page[limit]=10&include[]=resource1&include[]=resource2`

Take a look at the code  snippet here:-

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")  

    public String display(@RequestParam("name") String name,@RequestParam("pass") String pass,Model m)  
    {  
        if(pass.equals("admin"))  
        {  
            String msg="Hello "+ name;  
            //add a message to the model  
            m.addAttribute("message", msg);  
            return "viewpage";  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            String msg="Sorry "+ name+". You entered an incorrect password";  
            m.addAttribute("message", msg);  
            return "errorpage";  
        }     
    }  
}
```

you can create a seperate POJO (class containing all the keys as the private field and getters and setters) and use @ModelAttribute as the method argument
This would make the code tidy and increase understandability and convenience.

```
public class POJO{
String resouce1;
String resource2;
//getters & setters
}
```

In the Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(/path)
public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute POJO mypojo)
{
//statements
//statements
}
```

Hope this helps.
Would appreciate any further queries from your side.

Thank You.

Comment: What I'm missing in your answer is how `filters[status]` is mapped in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Binding the request parameters for GET API (web service) depends on the business requirement.
When you design a Rest API using “GET” method, there are couple of things to be considered.

1)  Most Important thing is “GET” method using standard is for retrieving data from database or any other data repository.

2)  When binding request parameters, you should consider the requirement of the API. Mainly there are two types of parameters according to the business requirements. mandatory parameters and optional parameters. As well as Rest web services also map above parameter type with path variable (@PathVariable) and request param (@RequestParam)

3)  For an example there is a API for search orders by order Id. So, without order id cannot search orders. Order id should be mandatory. You should use @PathVariable, when you design the API for this use case. This is a good coding practice. @PathParam reads the value from a path part of the called URI.

4)  @RequestParam can be used for implement optional parameters. Request param  are passed as a key value pair and therefore their orders irrelevant to more than one request param.

5)  you can add path variables and request params more than one as per the requirement.

6)  Then the URL is depends on path variables and request params. URL design as below. Request params are added after adding the all path variables and separate with question mark (**?**) you can add more request params separate with ampersand sign (**&**)

(http://www.example.com/ <@ PathVariable  > /? requestParamName = <@RequestParam >)

PathVariable implementation in GET method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/orders/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getOrder(@PathVariable final String id) {
  return "Order ID: " + id;
}
```

RequestParam implementation in GET method

```
@RequestMapping("/trades", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showTradeDetails(@RequestParam String tradeId,Model model){
  model.addAttribute("tradeId", tradeId);
  return "tradeDetails";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter object to pass in body request to your GET method:

```
Filter : {
    status:"active"
    org : {
           country :"IND"     
           }
...

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is highly unrecommended to pass so many query params in a GET call, in case you have so many parameters its better to convert the api of type POST.

Comment: Please can you give any explanation or references why this whould be "unrecommended"?

Comment: Yeah sure, hope you are aware about the security issues. As of now, have you added some kind of authorisation to this API, if not then when you make a GET call passing the entire big query params, you will end up highlighting the same in your browser and just by tampering the API request some other users Data can be fatched. To avoid the same, if you convert the API call to be of POST type this will not only avoid the entire long query params and also POST calls are secure.

Answer (score -1):

In this article [Spring Boot: How to design efficient REST API?](https://medium.com/quick-code/spring-boot-how-to-design-efficient-search-rest-api-c3a678b693a0), I explained how to develop a REST API for search. As an example, you found the code and screenshots of postman in this article.
Testing API in live it's possible too like this:
https://efficient-search-api.herokuapp.com/api/cars?country=USA&sort=createDate,desc&limit=100&offset=2

As optimization with one endpoint, I can get several results: resources are sorted, filtered, and paginated.

You do not deal with a lot of code (check of query param and all the control in your controller): the library specification-arg-resolver makes that with no problem